# Macro to Consolidate names and add quantities from multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have an Excel template that I am working on as a tool for our department, and it has multiple sheets that can be copied, and what it ultimately does, is compile data from the first few sheets to create a list of sheet goods to be produced in our manufacturing facility. Each line item consists of a quantity, and then a core material, and two faces. This list is a separate sheet, that can be copied to create many different lists all referencing data from the same first three sheets.

I need to be able to quickly, and in a somewhat automated process, create a secondary list from the data of the first list. The secondary list needs to tell give me a total of each unique core, face, and backer. Some of the backers are the same as the face, so those should be consolidated.

I have a macro already that can allow the user to select a range of data, and then it spits out a consolidated list with quantities and names. The problem is this only works for 3 columns of data, and uses the 3rd column as the name, and the first as the quantity. I haven't figured out how to get it to look to columns of data that are not exactly adjacent, or more than 3 columns.

I am much more comfortable with spreadsheet formulas, but I'm thinking a macro would be the best solution if I can figure it out, as the end users of this spreadsheet have limited knowledge of excel, and I don't want to rely on them memorizing a bunch of steps.

[First List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdf4G.png)
[Start of Second List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XzZ5.png)

Here is the macro I have so far.

```
 Sub Macro1()

Dim i, J, K, L, M, R1, R1F, C1F, Temp As Integer
Dim SemiFinalData(500, 2) As Variant
Dim FinalData(500, 2) As Variant

i = J = 0

Set InputData = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the full range of Data (Qty Through Description)", Type:=8)
R1 = InputData.Rows.Count 'Gets Data to Summarize and Counts the Number of Rows

For i = 1 To R1
    If InputData(i, 3) <> "" Then
        SemiFinalData(J, 0) = InputData(i, 1)
        SemiFinalData(J, 1) = InputData(i, 2)
        SemiFinalData(J, 2) = InputData(i, 3)
        J = J + 1
    End If
Next i  'Extracts Non-Blank Data into Array

M = 0
For i = 0 To J - 1  'Loops for each value in SemifinalData
    L = 0
    For K = 0 To J - 1    'Second loop for each value in SemifinalData
        If SemiFinalData(i, 2) = FinalData(K, 2) Then 'Counter for Duplication Test
            L = L + 1
        End If
    Next K
    If L < 1 Then    'Tests for Duplication and Extracts Data to FinalData Array
        FinalData(M, 1) = SemiFinalData(i, 1)
        FinalData(M, 2) = SemiFinalData(i, 2)
        M = M + 1
    End If
Next i

For i = 0 To M - 1
    Temp = 0
    For K = 0 To J - 1
        If FinalData(i, 2) = SemiFinalData(K, 2) Then
            Temp = Temp + SemiFinalData(K, 0)
        End If
    Next K
    FinalData(i, 0) = Temp
Next i





Set OutputData = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the first Cell of Output Range (for Qty)", Type:=8)
R1F = OutputData.Row
C1F = OutputData.Column  'Gets Row/Column for Start of Output Range

For K = 0 To 2
    Cells(R1F, C1F + K).Select
    For i = 0 To M - 1
        Selection = FinalData(i, K)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select  'Writes Data to Sheet
    Next i
Next K


End Sub
```

Essentially I am struggling with the 3 types of data on the same row from the first list, and the best way to separate them onto their own line on the second sheet.

Comment: By the way, your first line of variable declarations is only declaring `Temp` as `Integer`.  The rest are `Variant`.  You need to do each one, even when all on the same line.  Also, I suggest using `Long` and not `Integer`.  VBA will convert it to `Long` internally, but you will be limited to a maximum value of about 2^15 with `Integer`.

Comment: Thank you. This is actually someone else's Macro that came before me, and I am trying to reverse engineer it as a jumping off point. I appreciate the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at using 
`Worksheets().range().AdvancedFilter(....)`
This could help you pick out the data that you are looking for much easier. [Check the office vba reference for more details.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841242.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that out. I'm trying to find my way around the office vba reference site, but am finding it difficult to find what I am looking for. Still new to VBA.

Comment: I only started learning VBA in May, but I've written four different large reports for my company already. You can make things a lot simpler if you use variable names that are meaningful to you. In a subroutine I just wrote, I literally have variables called startRowIndex and endRowIndex. Also, if you're new to object oriented programming, it might be worth your while to brush up on that. Making your macro more modular can make it easier to code and easier to understand. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'm basically reverse engineering what I can so far. I've done a little java, some lisp, and a lot of spreadsheet work. Trying to get into macros as I'm finding they are better suited for a lot of what I want to do now. Any advice on where to look for documentation (other than on her)?

Comment: There is obviously [this here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff846392(v=office.14).aspx), but I honestly just google whenever I hit a road block. You would be amazed at how many times someone had the exact same problem that I did. Today was actually the first time in ~10000 lines of VBA since May that I couldn't find the answer to my question...and even then I realized that I had overlooked something really simple. I actually had a book that taught VBA use in excel and pretty much stopped using it after the first day.